# Split String on the basis of multiple delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string

my string contains

**{my office opens 24/7, if you have any question (query) contact with us.}**

and i want to break it into

> **{my}, {office}, {opens}, {24},{/}, {7}, {,}, {if}, {you}, {have}, {any},
>   {question}, {(}, {query}, {)}, {contact}, {with}, {us}, {.}**

means, if single literal of string is only contains characters or numbers separate it. if literal contain special character with characters or numbers, separate the characters before the special character, separate special character and separate characters after the special characters

I am looking for any solution, by using string.split(), or by using any other alternative logic. thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post an attempt at a solution

Comment: I think that could be achieved with regular expressions.

Comment: your string contains the character '{' ? or are you just put here to simbolize

Comment: no, '{' is just for presentation, here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String str = "my office opens 24/7, if you have any question (query) contact with us.";

String[] splited = str.split("(?=[()./,])|(?<=[()./,])|\\s");
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed by Rafael Battesti, this solution does not work with other specials characters like '@' or '%' for instance.

So, I think you could change the regex to

`String[] splited = str.split("(?=[\\W])|(?<=[\\W])");`

Comment: thank you for your response, i run your answer, it similar towards the solution but its not break the 24/7

Comment: @FarazSultan I've put the `\\s` outside the brackets to not preserve the whitespaces in the splited array, but if it worked then no problem :)

Comment: @Johnny Willer: What if I add another special character in the string? Lets say "$" or "@"? I think your answer is very good, but does not really comply with the requirements. I'm just being a nit picker and adding some debate. :-)

Comment: @RafaelBattesti yes, it was a lack of attention. I've updated my answer

Comment: @Johnny Willer: added another answer, what is actually only getting rid of the spaces left behind. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I will add up to your answer, as you had a very good regex! As i figured out this answer still leaves some whitespaces. I added some lines to generate the exact output that was asked. :-)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "my office opens 24$7, if you have any question (query) contact with us.";
        String[] split = str.split("(?=[\\W])|(?<=[\\W])|\\s");
        ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            if (!split[i].equals(" ")) {
                finalList.add(split[i]);
            }
        }

        //Test
        for (String i : finalList) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```